How to optimize glmnet cross validation on very large dataset in R
I have 1000 datasets with each database containing 2 million rows and 200 columns.
I have to run an elastic net regression on each of these 1000 datasets.
While running glmnet, the cv.glmnet takes around 7 minutes to do cross-validation for a single data set.
I tried to parallelize the process but it's working with a maximum of two cores only (RAM-16 GB and the dataset size is 2-3 GB). The time went down to 4 minutes.
This way, it will take a massive amount of time to run glmnet on all the datasets.
Is there a way to optimize this process? Any suggestions would be welcome.
